# Azure Pipelines: Compare test results between two dates

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I wonder if there is any way to compare test results between two specific dates, and see the differences, related to passed test cases, failed test cases.

[image: Example picture]

I started this mornings work by checking out the latest nightly builds and test results that we have, and I saw that the green line(Pass Rate) has somehow increased during this past weekend.

And this is interesting, as nobody has done any changes in the code base, nor the test suite.
So I want to see what test cases suddenly have started to pass.

Is there any way to do this, or maybe export test data for comparison in some other tool?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using [the Test Results Trend (Advanced) widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-test-results-trend?view=azure-devops) in dashboard, so you can monitor test trends over a period of time, detect patterns around test failures, test duration, and more, and generate actionable insights.

In addition, to get deeper insights and data you can view the Test Failure report in the pipeline. To learn more, see details [Analyze test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/test-analytics?view=azure-devops#view-test-analytics-for-builds). The build summary includes the **Analytics** page that hosts this report. The top-level view provides a summary of the test pass rate and results for the selected build pipeline, for the specified period. The default range is 14 days.

And [the source of information for test analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/test-analytics?view=azure-devops#report-information-source) is the set of [published test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops) for the build or release pipeline. These result are accrued over a period of time(also some artifacts, tests will be deleted due to retention policy), and form the basis of the rich insights that test analytics provides. Thus the data is not always the same.